# Trying to compare return values to list

Tags: python, list, random

randomgenerator() is a function that yields 6 random integers, the user is prompted to also enter 6 values which are added to lucky[].
I want to compare each yield value to the lucky[] list for a match, but the if condition is not being met.

```py
for x in randomgenerator():
      print(f"\n{x} is a winning number.")
      if x in lucky:
           print(f"There is a match with number {x}")
           match.append(x)
```

```
def randomgenerator():
    for i in range(5):
        yield random.randint(1,2)
    yield random.randint(1,2)
```

Comment: Can you provide the code of the randomgenerator function? And also sample input/output if possible.

Comment: If I had to guess, I'd say `x` is an `int` and `lucky` contains `strings` so they don't match (or vice versa).

Comment: Are you converting the user input numbers to `int`s? By default, the return type of `input()` is a `string`, so be sure that the user input is converted to an `int`.

Comment: What are the types of the values returned by `randomgenerator()`?  What are the types of the values in `lucky`?  Probably they aren't the same, and therefore equality is impossible.

Comment: @gnkko, since I now see your full code I can confirm that the suspects of the other users were correct and that my answer should work. Check it, if it works accept it, otherwise feel free to ask in the comments.

Comment: @FLAK-ZOSO thank you very much for your answer. It has worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You said `randomgenerator` returns a `tuple` containing `int`s.

> `randomgenerator()` is a function that yields 6 random *values*

I guess by "values" you meant `int`egers, since it's very strange to generate random `str`ings.

Then `lucky` is filled with `input()` returned values, which are `str`ings.

---

```
if str(x) in lucky: # This should work, since it will convert the int x to a string
```

a similar solution would be:

```
lucky = list(map(int, lucky)) # all the elements are converted to integers
```